# Determine protocol and cipher compatibility with server certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ecdsa

My server may be attached to a RSA or ECDSA certificate.

In my code I set the prtocol method as

```
sslmethod = SSLv23_server_method();
```

and setting the cipher using the SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() API.

The problem is when the server is attached to ECDSA certificate and if I pass "RSA" cipher SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() does not return any error though "RSA" cipher is not compatible with ECDSA certificates.

Is there any openssl API which I can use to find out if the cipher we are going to set is compatible with the certificate or with protocol or not?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any openssl API which I can use to find out if the cipher we are going to set is compatible with the certificate or with protocol or not?

If you author the app and own the server, then YES, you do know what to expect. But the general case is NO, you don't know in advance and you can't query for it. You try to setup a channel and if it fails, then you try something else.

Generally speaking, there's no way to know in advance what cipher suites a server supports; or what type of public key is bound in the server's certificate. In fact, there's no way to know what protocol versions (SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2, etc) a server supports. Its the reason for [RFC 7405, TLS Fallback Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV) for Preventing Protocol Downgrade Attacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7507).

In 2016/2017, about the best you can do is assume:

- No SSLv2, SSLv3; only TLS 1.0 and above
- Cipher suites from the collection "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!RC4:!MD5"

"!kRSA" is "no RSA key transport", and it means you can only use ephemeral key exchanges. If a server has a RSA key, then it will only be used for authentication. That is, the key will be used to sign the server's ephemeral values during key exchange so the client knows they are authentic.

Comment: Thanks JWW for the inputs. The developer / admin will be the owner of the server and he will be setting the ECDSA certificate and the cipher.
But instead of ourself looking some cipher list to find out ciphers compatible to the protocol we want some API which will do this for us.
In our code base it is impractical to add an array of vast avaliable ciphers and do the check ourself as it will slow down the server.
So we are looking for some SSL API.

Comment: The cost of key exchange will literally dwarf the cipher suite selection process. You could perform millions of cipher suite selections in the time its going to take to perform 100 key exchanges. Just use "TLS 1.0 and above", and a cipher suite string of `"HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!RC4:!MD5"`. As a tiny speedup, you could add `"!PSK:!SRP:!DSS"`. The cipher suites will keep you out of hot water under most threat models, and avoid problems with old IronPort and F5 proxies. Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Is there any SSL API which can tell whether a certificate will support a particular cipher or not like any EC cipher or a RSA cipher?